# Could we use microdata and JSON-LD for the same entities so they work well on Pinterest's rich pins?

Tags: microdata, structured-data, json-ld, microformats

we recently switched from microformats for recipes to JSON-LD markup for rich snippets, which worked a lot better in Google search result pages.
However, when we try to post a rich pin for recipes on Pinterest, we find that Pinterest cannot handle JSON-LD (yet).

Has anyone of you tried to use JSON-LD as well as microdata or microformats on one page, for the same entities? I know that you can mix these markups for different entities, but what if I mixed them for the very same entities?

Comment: Related question with focus on Google Search: [Should I use only one type of markup?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/90520/17633)